# How to decide on number of levels in MLM

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I am wondering if I should use multilevel modeling (MLM) in my analysis. Theoretically speaking, the data structure appears hierarchical, so from that point of view, I am inclined to use MLM.

But in case anybody is challenging me here, I would like to show that the numbers back up this decision, i.e. I want to show that there is sufficient variance at each level. Most sources I have seen recommend anywhere between 5% and 10% of variance they want to see on each level (although some also just say this criterion does not matter, and if the data has a hierarchical structure, one should always use MLM -- but let's assume I want to show some numbers).

My data structure is essentially:

```
Districts (D)
|
Schools (S)
|
Pupils (P)
|
Test score observations at various points in time (T)
```

So what I do now is to estimate a model that only includes P as a level (and no further covariates, etc.). I will then calculate my first ICC = (variance at level P) / (variance at level P + residual variance)

My understanding is that residual variance in this case is variance at level T.

Let's say I find my 5%/10% here, and wonder if I should add another level. What do I do now?

Do I run a model with levels P and S included? And how do I calculate the next ICC then? Do I take (variance at level S) / (variance at level S + variance at level P + residual variance) ?